# Firebase cloud function run out of memory

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I use firebase's cloud function and got a problem. I know cloud functions can set memory like this
runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540, memory: '8GB' }).https.onCall

I've set the memory to 8g, but it's still not enough I need to get all players' docs and write something to another collection. My player number is about 30k+. and when I get all players' docs it always says run out of memory. See picture below
[image]

Do you know how to handle this? Many thanks.

Comment: 8GB is indeed the max memory for Firebase Functions, which means you need to focus on _not_ hitting that memory limit. Can you share the code for your function? It's possible that you're doing something very inefficient _or_ including a library that uses a ton of memory.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your help!
I need to get all players' ID and send in-game mails to them like this below

  console.log("A");
  const playerDataSnapshot = await db.collection('PlayerData').where("Initialized", "==", true).get();
  console.log("B");

but this line will run out of memory. I only get console log  "A"  but not   "B"
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How many documents are in your collection? And how big is the data? If the collection is _huge_ it's possible that it's too big for the function to hold in memory. If not, it's probably not the query itself that's causing this... it's just the proverbial straw that broke the camel's back. What libraries are you importing? Can you post a full [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Tim For now, it's roughly 32416 docs in a collection, but it's still growing. I am not sure how big a doc is. These are all columns of a doc. https://imgur.com/a/i5D2NqN.

I simply call this in cloud function and it will run out of memory.
const playerDataSnapshot = await db.collection('PlayerData').where("Initialized", "==", true).get();

Comment: I believe I shouldn't put some data in this doc. Maybe put part of the data in another collection (e.x.  BuyLimitShopItems in a separate collection) but it will still run out of memory in the future.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't have a ton of detail, but it wouldn't surprise me if each document was 250KB... with 32K documents you'd definitely bump up against that 8GB limit.Firebase functions aren't really intended for long-running, high-memory processes. In cases where you start bumping up against the time/memory limits, you usually need to take another approach, like splitting things up or using a different offering from Google Cloud. If you provide more context about what you're trying to accomplish and why, I can give you suggestions on how to rearchitect.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I am going to send in-game mail to all of my users. All players will receive 
a mail including a reward item. So at first, I am trying to get all players' data so I know who to send, but I am stuck here.

Comment: you should paginate your query and send batches of mail at a time.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was to fully log the Axios response object.

After reducing the size of my logs, my function no longer had a memory problem and could end normally.